# PHP and MySQL, call_user_func_array doesn't work with variable as argument

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to set up a dynamic MySQL query, using mysqli prepared statements. I need to compare multiple values (unknown how many) to a single column.

The following works:

```
$qs = '?,?';
$query = 'SELECT r_id FROM sometable WHERE someindex IN ('.$qs.')';
$statement = $db_conn->prepare($query);
call_user_func_array(array($statement, 'bind_param'), array('ss', 'Something', 'somethingelse'));
```

I get a result back from the DB, and can do as I please with the return. BUT, the following does *not* work:

```
$qs = '?,?';
$query = 'SELECT r_id FROM sometable WHERE someindex IN ('.$qs.')';
$statement = $db_conn->prepare($query);
$test = array('ss', 'Something', 'something else');
call_user_func_array(array($statement, 'bind_param'), $test);
```

With the only difference being the assignment of `$test`, instead of creating the array directly within `call_user_func_array`.

Similarly:

```
$one = 'pizza';
$two = 'pie';
call_user_func_array(array($statement, 'bind_param'), array('ss', $one, $two));
```

also does *not* work. The statement doesn't even execute.

If I can't put variable names directly into the statement, I can't have the dynamic queries. What's going on? Is there a fix for this, or maybe another (equally simple) way I can run a query on a single column, with an unknown number of terms? References or pointers (i.e. `&$one`) do not work either.

There seems to be a couple known issues with `call_user_func_array` back in 2012, or around there, but I can't find anything more recent. I am using PHP 5.5

**EDIT 1**

Known issue, back in 2007 [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43568)

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting = E_ALL` and display_errors enabled? You said the statement doesn't execute, but did not indicate any errors received. This functionality should be supported. Check `echo $conn->error` and make sure php is reporting errors. In the first case, it is probably a values vs references error.

Comment: You wouldn't have that issue with PDO `$statement->execute($array_with_values);`. I can't really help with MySQLI and the bug report says it has been fixed back in 2008. The first comment on the php manual page to bind param function seems to have a working workaround http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: What you likely need is `array('ss', &$one, &$two)`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I took your advice. I'm always reluctant to adopt new methods, when my old ones have done me so well up to this point. But yeah, the PDO is much better.